# Send the next Row if we skip the previous Row in DB

Tags: php, database

I have a php script that runs every 20 minutes (I use screen on Debian - server side),

The php script selects the first row of the Database using LIMIT 1, like:

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1");
```

Once selected the first Row it will send the result to a telegram bot, delete the 1st row from the DB and the scripts ends.

It repeats this process every 20 minutes cause the screen.

Now, the question is, if the first row I got with LIMIT 1 doesn't meet the criteria (at the moment it is deleted and skip the actual process until the next 20 minutes), how can I make it to select the 2nd row (which is now the 1st row again) to get the new data using the same script and avoiding wait the next 20 minutes?
Is it possible with my actual script LIMIT 1?

Comment: you can combine it with where: `WHERE is_deleted=0 LIMIT 1` to get the first record that complies to the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I don't have access to your database, and I don't know what your criteria are, so this will all be pseudocode.  I am assuming you will want to delete the first row if it doesn't match the criteria, but it would be just as possible to only skip it:

```
$finished = false;

while(!$finished) {
  
  // you already have the code to get the first row.  It goes here.
  // I will assume those results are in $row
  
  $finished = $row MEETS CRITERIA; // whatever these criteria are
  
  // you also have the code to delete the current row.  put that here
  // whether this row satisfies the condition or not.  The row you 
  // just selected will always be deleted
  
}
```

It's as simple as that.  If the row met the criteria, then $finished is TRUE and the while loop will terminate*.  If the row didn't meet the criteria, the $finished is FALSE and the while loop will run again.  It will run until a row meets the criteria and $finished is TRUE.

* ! is the php NOT operator.  It inverts the value.  So basically what the while loop is saying is this:
`while not finished { do this code }`

Also, to avoid a non-terminating loop, you'll need to make sure that your result set has something in it, or else $finished will never be set to TRUE.  I'm not sure how you're executing, so I'm not going to suggest an implementation.  Just be aware that it is possible for a while to become a neverending loop and take measures to avoid it.  For instance, you might:

```
$finished = false;
$retries = 5;

while(!$finished && $retries-->0) {
  
  //the code
  
}
```

This decrements $retries every loop, and once it gets to 0 the while will stop no matter what.  It's a good idea to put a failsafe in any loop that might accidentally (or unforeseenedly) become unterminated, especially during development, so you don't hang your code.

---

EDITED now that I have seen some of the sample code:

```
$finished = false;
$retries = 5;

while(!$finished && $retries-->0) {

  $q = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1");
  $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);

  $e = $r['id'];
  $asin_queue = $r['asin'];
  $price_queue = $r['new_price'];
  
  $r = file_get_contents("https://api.keepa.com/product?asin=$asin_queue&key=$api_keepa");
  $gz = gzdecode($r);
  $t = json_decode($gz);
  $new_price = $t->products[0]->csv;  
  
  // put any other stuff you need to do here, 
  // like updating any db entries, etc

  // you also have the code to delete the current row.  put that here
  // whether this row satisfies the condition or not.  The row you 
  // just selected will always be deleted

  $finished = $new_price <= $price_queue;

}
```

And that's pretty much it.  It's your existing code, just wrapped in a while block so that it loops.  The only thing I've added is a line to check for a condition inside the while block so that the code knows when to exit.

Also, let's look at this: `$retries-->0`, because that line may be a little confusing.  So I said you needed some kind of failsafe to keep your code from accidentally looping forever if you make a mistake or oversight, and so I assign a variable `$retries` and make it equal to 5.  -- is php shorthand for "subtract one from this", so $retries-- just subtracts one from whatever the value is currently*.  `>0` is just a value check, even though I wrote it so it all runs together, it's two separate things.  It could have been written like this: `$retries-- > 0`.

In context of the while loop, there's a few things happening:

```
while( !$finished && $retries-->0 ) {}
```

and the whole thing has to evaluate to TRUE for the loop to keep running. && is the logical operator AND.  ! is the logical operator NOT.  So in plain language terms that condition would read:

"while not finished and the number of remaining retries is greater than 0, continue looping."

Hope all this helps.

---

* -- can go before or after the variable it's modifying.  If it goes after (`$retries--`) then the decrement doesn't take effect immediately.  This lets you use the variable in a logical test before the decrement is applied.  5-- > 4 is true.  If you put the -- before the variable, the decrement happens first.  --5 > 4 would be false, because the subtraction will happen before the comparison.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for replying back!
I have added some of my code, so you can understand better :)

Comment: As I understood it, what you were doing already was 1) selecting the first row from the database 2) performing some operations 3) deleting that row.  You did this every twenty minutes.  Is that correct?  And now the only change you want to make is to select the first row, perform some operations, delete the row and THEN if it didn't match some criteria then repeat the process until you find a row that does.  But the row you select is always getting deleted, rigth?

Comment: Correct, the first row would be deleted either way! Have you got any idea on how can I achieve/implement this?

Comment: Well, think of it this way.  You've already got 90% of that code.  You're already selecting the first row.  Done.  You're already deleting it when you're done.  You're already making your calculations.  Done and done.  All you have to do is figure out how to get it to repeat until you meet the right conditions.  That's what a while loop does:  while(condition is true) { loop code }.  So you just want to wrap what you already have in a while block and then set up an appropriate condition to tell the loop when to exit.

Comment: @Daniele see if that edit makes sense to you.  I just took your sample code and put it inside a while block.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you so much, it works very well!! Sometimes we don’t think at the easiest thing 

Comment: It's always the easiest thing that gets you.  Glad this worked for you.  If this helped you please select it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just realised that I never close the database connection and I think it is using a lot of CPU usage now, I can see it is mysql using htop command. Can I just add mysqli_close($con); at the bottom of every php file I have that uses the DB connection? Will that work? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is good to explicitly close the connection, but I also think that the connection will automatically close once your script ends, whether you close it manually or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying back!

I think I can use your suggestion but I need to edit it, the check I need to perform is as follows:

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1");
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);

    $e = $r['id'];
    $asin_queue = $r['asin'];
    $price_queue = $r['new_price'];
```

//perform the check to see if the price has changed

```
$r = file_get_contents("https://api.keepa.com/product?asin=$asin_queue&key=$api_keepa");

    $gz = gzdecode($r);

    $t = json_decode($gz);

    //price updated
    $new_price = $t->products[0]->csv;
```

//here is where I am stuck
I should do something like this:

```
while($new_price > $price_queue){
```

*// It will need to delete the first row on the DB and do the check again, until it get the right condition $new_price <= $price_queue and then it can quit the while loop.

//repeat the above to do the check again*

```
$q = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1");

$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);

    $e = $r['id'];
    $asin_queue = $r['asin'];
    $price_queue = $r['new_price'];
```

//perform the check to see if the price has changed

```
$r = file_get_contents("https://api.keepa.com/product?asin=$asin_queue&key=$api_keepa");

    $gz = gzdecode($r);
    $t = json_decode($gz);

    //price updated
    $new_price = $t->products[0]->csv;
```

}

Comment: hey, give me a little bit and then if nobody else has gotten around to it and you haven't already figured it out, I'm going to go back and edit some of your code back into my original answer so you can see it in place.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just realised that I never close the database connection and I think it is using a lot of CPU usage now, I can see it is mysql using htop command. Can I just add mysqli_close($con); at the bottom of every php file I have that uses the DB connection? Will that work? Thanks!